# Is there a proper name for $x^\dagger A y$

Tags: linear-algebra

If $x$, $y$, and $A$ are all real then we say $x^TAy$ is bilinear. In there a more general term for $x^\dagger Ay$, when the elements can be complex?

Comment: Also called as Quadratic form

Comment: No, I guess it's a hermitian form since he uses the dagger symbol.

Comment: We call it sesquilinear form. In the case where $A$ is definite positive we call it hermitian form.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you write is called a sesquilinear form : linear in the second variable and semi-linear in the first (sometimes the order is reversed, it sort of depends if you prefer left or right modules).

If furthermore $A$ is a hermitian matrix (ie $A^\dagger = A$), then it is a hermitian form.